# Can I install an air switch inside a cabinet?

Tags: water-purification

Need some advice on installing tap on the sink on quartz countertop.  Currently I have an air switch for grinder on the countertop.  Thinking of removing that and install it inside the cabinet (definitely not leaving it hanging) then using that hole to install tap for the RO system.

Any cons going this approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Messy.  You'll be constantly opening and closing the cabinet door and reaching inside it with wet hands.  Water in the cabinet could cause mold, delamination, and swelling especially of manufactured wood parts.

Dangerous.  If you drop in a spoon or something instead of about 0.3 seconds to turn it off, it's more like 1.5.  Try it!  Not with a real spoon, use a carrot.

Consider a new disposal with a magnetic switch in the lid.

Comment: This is why I prefer momentary switches for disposals, there's even less reaction time if you're already pressing the button/rocker.

Comment: @dandavis agreed.  But if the switch is momentary I would add a third paragraph to my answer.   Not sure the heading .. "slapstick"? ;).  If you can't use the continuous disposal function that's another argument in favor of the mag switch.

Answer (score 1):

There is a *safety* advantage to keeping the disposal control on top of the counter so you can see exactly what is happening when you turn it on. My disposal originally had the switch (regular toggle switch, not air switch) inside the cabinet and I really didn't like that.

It shouldn't be all that hard to drill another hole in the counter. A diamond hole saw should do the job.